# Android click listener on View work in strange manner

Tags: android, view, clicklistener

I have the following layout.xml containing one ScrollView with some elements(picture and text)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/clickable"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/crown" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/n1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="some text" />

        </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/medal" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/n2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="some text" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/star" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/n3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="some text" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

LayoutInflater inflater;
RelativeLayout MyLayout;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        MyLayout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.id.layout, null, false);
        MyLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d("TAG"," I'm clicked! ");
            }
        });
```

Click Listener above does not work when I click screen!!!
But if I change code to this - everything is working

```
MyLayout.findViewById(R.id.clickable).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d("TAG"," I'm clicked! ");
            }
    });
```

So why should I set click listener to LinearLayout inside ScrollView inside parent RelativeLayout?
Why click listener does not work for root xml element RelativeLayout???

Comment: What is your parent RelativeLayout doing if your content is really scrolling? So, ScrollView should be your parent.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your ScrollView is intercepting the touch events and not propagating them to parent layouts (in this case your RelativeLayout).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25839816/how-to-prevent-scrollview-from-intercepting-click-touch-events-of-the-view-behin) thread might have some useful information about this topic.

Comment: Hi Jonas! I tried to add id to ScrollView like I do to LinearLayout inside ScrollView android:id="@+id/clickable" , but it does not work. Means ScrollView does not listen to clicks by some unknown reason. The only solution working is as I wrote in the request. It looks like some Android bug-feature for me... Very strange!

Answer (score 0):

Just add  `android:clickable="false"` in your `ScrollView`. Then change your MainActivity like below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

LinearLayout myLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    myLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("TAG"," I'm clicked! ");
        }
    });
}
```

}

**Note:** activity_main.xml is xml file which you are loading.

Now your `OnClick` will work as expected.

Comment: Hi Fahad! I did tried to set up android:clickable="false"  everywhere on ScrollView and LinearLayouts , but it did not help to me. The only click listener working was only on LinearLayout inside my ScrollView... It looks very strange.